# Alternate to if:false in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom

Now salesforce is going to deprecate **if:true** & **if:false** and the alternate to these 2 tags is **lwc:if**, **lwc:elseIf** and **lwc:else**

Now replacing **if:true** is simple, just change it to **lwc:if** but if I want to change if:false then either I have to write an empty **lwc:if** and then another tag with **lwc:else** or I have to change the data which renders element only when it is truthy.

for example

```
<template if:false={myStatement}>
   <!--my elements -->
</template>
```

now with the new tags either render my elements only when myStatement is true or write it like below

```
<template lwc:if={myStatement}>
    <!--I have nothing to render here because I have to render my components only when myStatement is false
</template>
<template lwc:else>
    <!--my elements -->
</template>
```

If it is about only one getter then I can understand it can be changed easily but what if we have
data in some array where we are going to render some component only if a particular array element is false in that case either I have to use an empty lwc:if along with another lwc:else tag or I have to unnecessarily change the data inside my array to render the component when the element of my array is true.

Moreover these new tags also don't support complex condition like below

```
<template lwc:if={!myStatement}>
</template>
```

I have spent a good amount of time on the internet read the documentation again and again but I could not find any right alternate to **if:false**

If my understanding is incorrect related to these new tags then I would highly apricate if you point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I'm aware, you are meant to use either of the two solutions. I would personally recommend flipping the Boolean value, as that is a trivial code change. This is actually similar to most other frameworks, including Visualforce. In our own project, for example, we currently have less than 20 `if:false`, and all of them are attached to a nearby `if:true`. This reduces the number of evaluations the runtime needs to make, improving performance, and it also eliminates the `if:true`/`if:false` bugs when you do unexpected things with them, like this: `<c-lwc if:true={flag1} if:false={flag2}></c-lwc>`. This example can crash the render cycle unexpectedly. The newer directives are checked by compiler to avoid this class of problems.

Comment: Thank you for your response but in my project I need to hide something based on certain conditions my if:false is not attached to any if:true now flipping the Boolean means to retest everything.

Comment: @gs650x That's what unit tests are for. In theory, if you had tests set up, you'd flip a bit somewhere, update the template, run your tests, and you're done. Your comment is that when something is true you need to *hide* something, you should think of it as when the opposite is true, I need to *show* something. I'd say this is a best practice in general. You'd have to do that exact kind of thinking if you were using Visualforce or React, for example.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like this is possible at the moment if you want to use lwc:if instead of if:false, refer to this [https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-conditional.html][1]

But you can negate the statement in the JS:

```
mystatement;

get isNotMyStatement() {
    return !this.myStatement;
}
```

In the HTML:

```
<template lwc:if={isNotMyStatement}></template>
```